# how to set codeigniter cron in ubuntu with apache

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, cron

I am using Codeigniter to develop my site and it's running on Apache installed in Ubuntu.

I want to run a cron. I am using Codeigniter routing and  I have also removed `index.php` from route.

My controller is home function is winner.

I tried following two ways but no one seems to be working.

```
#49 5 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/project/web/index.php home winner

13 6 * * * /usr/bin/curl http://www.project.com/home/winner
```

Comment: are you trying to run cron job ?

Comment: yes @HardikPaghdar its my question

Comment: Create one controller and model and make function call to direct URL nothing to more..are making wab service in CI ? same process in Cron

Comment: @HardikPaghdar come on man, what are you saying I already have a controller and a function, I dont need model for my task and when I am hitting direct url its giving me result.

Comment: i am saying make this type of function and set your server to this url in cpanal

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that lynx installed in your system (e.g. command "whereis lynx")
2. Then edit crontab's config (command "crontab -e")
3. Put this command with MAILTO option in your crontab's config (in the same order, on the first line "mailto" option, on the next line other options):

MAILTO=your@email.com

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/lynx -source http://www.project.com/home/winner

With those settings cron will be start every 5 minutes. And if will be some errors there, cron will send it email on address that you set in MAILTO option.

[Tested on Debian 4.7.2]

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your cPanel cron job setup. 
This is to run every 5 minutes:

```
 */5 * * * * curl http://yoursite.com/class/function
```

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/setting-up-cron-for-drupal/configuring-cron-jobs-using-the-cron-command

Comment: I dont have cpanel. I am running it via terminal (ubuntu)

Comment: I have tried 5 * * * * curl http://www.example.com/home/winner but its not working :(

Comment: not able to get that exactly but I tried 5 * * * * curl example.com/home/winner and not working

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13755039)

Comment: @beerwin absolutely right. that link has lots of content, I tried it as well but didnt work